# Webcam streaming client to client. Chat

Tags: c#, asp.net, webcam

I'm coding an web app working in browsers. The backend server is Windows and I use ASP.

I'm trying to set up an chat where it streams web cams to each other. But i'm unsure of what to use.

It is similar to http://www.chatroulette.com.

I've heard something about flash media server, but I'm looking at the easiest way to do this.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If it's C# it means ASP.NET not classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [getUserMedia()](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html) function of Html5 will do what you want without flash or or silverlight. This is a part of the new Html5 functionality to capture and stream video/audio to the website. I think it is also possible to upload it to your server and make sure you are sending it to the other user you're chatting with.

This is some logic your server needs to do not the html5 function.
I hope this helps in you quest. here you can find some nice [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) about the getUserMedia